# Check if package is installed using pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pipenv

Is there a way to check if a particular package is installed using pipenv?
I have a `Makefile` which runs `pipenv run <command>` but I want to show a friendly message if the package is not installed and ask users to run `pipenv install`.

Currently the run command just creates new `vitrualenv` and just fails with command not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what dependencies are installed in [two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54307614/328817): `pipenv run pip freeze` or `pipenv graph`.

You can then use `grep` on the output of this.  `grep` returns 0 if it matches something, or non-zero if it doesn't, and you can [check the return value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29370/how-to-check-if-a-command-succeeded) by examining `$?`.

Putting it all together, you can do something like this:

```bash
pipenv run pip freeze | grep mypackage
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "mypackage isn't installed; run pipenv install mypackage"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to call the interpreter with a minimal code and then check the return code and based on the code display the message you want.

Something like this:

```
all:
    @python -c "import mypackage" 2>/dev/null|| (echo "";echo "error message";echo ""; exit 1)
```