# How can I see the current version of packages installed by pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm managing my Python dependencies with [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  How can see the currently installed versions of packages?

I could examine `Pipfile.lock`, but is there a simpler way from the command line?

Comment: Note that the contents of `Pipfile.lock` might not necessarily match the installed packages.

Comment: @Flimm could you explain more about situations in which that might be the case?

Comment: For example, you could have `pipenv install` and then `pipenv run pip uninstall packagename` , in that case, the package would be deleted from the virtualenv directory without modifying `Pipfile` or `Pipfile.lock`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1.go in project folder.
2.first activate pipenv type `pipenv shell`.
3.type `pip freeze`

Comment: This answer is about virtualenv, not pipenv.  However, since both use pip "behind the scenes", what you suggest can actually work in a slightly modified form: `pipenv run pip freeze` (it's important to run in the pipenv context as otherwise you get global deps, not project-specific ones).  Update your answer to suggest that and I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2fNEoZfuy8  check this pip freeze works in pipenv too. Go on  3:00 minute of video

Comment: yes, `pip freeze` works in pipenv - see my previous comment.  But step 2 of your project is about virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for updating to make it refer to pipenv.  This is really helpful now.

Comment: I am curious to know why you did not prefer to use  `pip list` instead. It works too. However, I am not sure if it shows packages installed in `pipenv` or in global. Open to any feedbacks on this.

Comment: In one line: `pipenv run pip freeze`

Comment: `pip freeze` seems to no longer work with `pipenv`, instead use `pipenv lock -r` as suggested by @Dr Neo.

Answer (score 52):

To see installed packages with Pipenv, you can use the [`pipenv graph`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pipenv-graph) command.

The output from this is perhaps more verbose than you'd like, but it does contain everything you need.

Sample truncated output:

```bash
appdirs==1.4.3
decorator==4.0.11
flake8==3.3.0
  - configparser [required: Any, installed: 3.5.0]
  - enum34 [required: Any, installed: 1.1.6]
  - mccabe [required: >=0.6.0,<0.7.0, installed: 0.6.1]
  - pycodestyle [required: >=2.0.0,<2.4.0, installed: 2.3.1]
  - pyflakes [required: >=1.5.0,<1.6.0, installed: 1.5.0]
Flask-Admin==1.5.3
  - Flask [required: >=0.7, installed: 0.12.4]
    - click [required: >=2.0, installed: 6.7]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.21, installed: 0.24]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.4, installed: 2.10]
      - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.23, installed: 1.0]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.7, installed: 0.14.1]
  - wtforms [required: Any, installed: 2.1]
```

As it's a graph, you'll sometimes need to look in "deeper" levels of the output for the package you're interested in.  You can also use `grep`:

```bash
$ pipenv graph | grep Flask-Admin
Flask-Admin==1.5.3
```

Comment: I actually prefer @dvijparekh's answer now that has been updated for `pipenv`, since that gives more concise output.

Comment: I think this is more useful if you want to keep track of your dependencies. Also this helped me to verify that `pip list` does the work fine.

Answer (score 7):

Seems `pip list` works too

1.go in project folder.

2.activate pipenv `$ pipenv shell`.

3.`$ pip list`

Comment: In one line: `pipenv run pip list`

Answer (score 3):

Just use command `pipenv lock -r`

This will list locally installed packages. 
-r, --requirements  Generate output in requirements.txt format

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of why this answer is the most suitable.

Comment: This command is used to generate the content of  requirements.txt, the former version of Pipfile and Pipfile.lock. See https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#generating-a-requirements-txt

Comment: This is not the same as listing the installed packages. It converts `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` without looking at which packages are installed.

Answer (score 1):

### Pipenv has the answer

I do believe the author of `pipenv` suggests using in production the command:

```py
pipenv lock --requirements 
# or simply use : pipenv lock -r
```

but since this will work only if you start from scratch a new project, and after that you use `pipenv lock` then you copy the `pipfile.lock` to the new directory (either a deployed dir or a new project).
I attach a diagram on how I understand `pipenv` I hope it is useful. I highly suggest using method A. that will allow you to see the full list of all installed libraries. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Every `pipenv` has its own pipfile in which all the packages installed are listed. It also lets you manually enter a package name in the Pipfile for installation.

Hence, I do use Pipfile to check what packages are installed in the current environment.

- For VS Code run within the environment directory:
  `code Pipfile`
- For VIM:
  `vim Pipfile`

Comment: This is not the same as seeing which packages are installed. The `Pipfile` (or `Pipfile.lock`) could have different packages listed than the ones that are installed in reality.